# Minecraft greed trap

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm making a trap so that when an object is removed from the pressure plate, it blows up. But Im a bit stuck. The pressure plate does not change the state of the redstone torch on the endblock. I need it to be on when an item is removed from the pressure plate, thus blowing up the player.[image]

Comment: Next time better make screenshots with your Computer not with your camera.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove the top torch and replace it with redstone to do what you want. In fact you can even remove the first two wood blocks and replace them with redstone.

This design has a serious flaw, though: the dropped item will despawn after 5 minutes, causing the trap to activate even if there is no player around. To work around that, you can use a dispenser and a long timer. After e.g. 4.5 minutes measured by the timer, the dispenser would drop another item on the pressure plate, so when the first item despawns, the pressure plate will still be on.

Here is an idea how to do that: [image: player detection by item pickup]

There are two pressure plates, both of which have items on them. The right one is the player detector. When the item is picked up, the signal is sent to the noteblock. If for 5 minutes no one picks the item, *both* items will despawn simultaneously and the left pressure plate will send a signal to immediately shoot another two items. The short pulse on the right will not activate the noteblock because of the pulse filter (made with repeaters and a NOR gate). The two stone blocks in front of the dispensers are only used to direct the items to fall down on the pressure plate.

Comment: How do you make a long timer. Im kinda new to minecraft.

Comment: Sadly, building a long timer is not very easy and all existing designs take a lot of space. Look for example at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yU0gRITjzu0 where water pushes items over soulsand. Other ideas may involve a lot of redstone ciquitry and/or or minecarts. Most of the long timer designs I have seen rely exactly on the 5 minute delay of item despawning, so they can't be used to measure anything less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @mrminecraft3000 Actually I got an idea how to do this in a simple way and edited the answer to describe it.